# jquery-mobile image not loading in popup when using WebView

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, webview

I am trying to show a popup window with an image and two buttons (close,open new window) in a WebView widget in my android app but when I tap on popup button I get no image. it only show two buttons and not target image.

```
<a href="#photo1" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"><img alt="" src="thumb.jpeg" class="grayborder"></a>

<div data-role="popup" data-history="false" id="photo{$stream.post_id}" data-overlay-theme="a"   data-corners="false">
<a href="#" onclick="return closePopup('#photo1');" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">close</a><a href="URLHERE" rel="external" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">open new window</a><img alt="" src="myimage.jpeg" class="photopopup">
</div>
```